# I created a date calculator with JavaScript, but I can't update the number even though setInterval()

Tags: javascript

```js
const clock = document.querySelector('.js-clock');
const text = clock.querySelector("p");

function getTime() {
  const xmasDay = new Date("2021-12-24:00:00:00+0900");
  const now = new Date();
  const gap = xmasDay - now;
  const day = Math.ceil(gap / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hour = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const min = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const sec = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  text.innerText = `${day}d ${hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : hour}h ${
    min < 10 ? `0${min}` : min
  }m ${sec < 10 ? `0${sec}` : sec}s`;
}
function init() {
  getTime();  
  setInterval(getTime(),1000);
}
init();
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Time until chrismas</h1>
    <div class="js-clock">
    <p></p>
    </div>
    <script src="1.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I can't speak English, so I ask questions using a translator.
The date and time doesn't updated
Is there a wrong code sentence?
I wish I could get some help.

Answer (score 3):

By appending parentheses to the getTime call in `setInterval`, you're calling that function and setting the callback for the interval to its returned value, rather than the function itself.

```js
const clock = document.querySelector('.js-clock');
const text = clock.querySelector("p");

function getTime() {
  const xmasDay = new Date("2021-12-24:00:00:00+0900");
  const now = new Date();
  const gap = xmasDay - now;
  const day = Math.ceil(gap / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hour = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const min = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const sec = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  text.innerText = `${day}d ${hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : hour}h ${
    min < 10 ? `0${min}` : min
  }m ${sec < 10 ? `0${sec}` : sec}s`;
}

function init() {
  getTime();
  setInterval(getTime, 1000);
}
init();
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Time until chrismas</h1>
  <div class="js-clock">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <script src="1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Remove the parentheses so you're passing `setInterval` a reference to the function, rather than its return value.

Comment: Oh, it's working fine! Thank you.
I'm ashamed of myself for being embarrassed by this one little problem. I think I need to study more.

Comment: Please can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick icon next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use eval method to get ouput

```js
const clock = document.querySelector('.js-clock');
const text = clock.querySelector("p");
function getTime() {
  const xmasDay = new Date("2021-12-24:00:00:00+0900");
  const now = new Date();
  const gap = xmasDay - now;
  const day = Math.ceil(gap / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hour = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const min = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const sec = Math.ceil((gap % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  text.innerText = `${day}d ${hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : hour}h ${
    min < 10 ? `0${min}` : min
  }m ${sec < 10 ? `0${sec}` : sec}s`;
}
function init() {
  setInterval(eval("getTime"),1000);
}
init();
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Time until chrismas</h1>
    <div class="js-clock">
    <p id="td"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="1.js"></script>
  </body>
```